# Mapquest routing using multiple stops(via) in OL3

Tags: openlayers, mapquest

I am trying to find the route between two stops in Mapquest by passing the lat long details in the URL,

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&outFormat=json&routeType=fastest&timeType=1&enhancedNarrative=false&shapeFormat=raw&generalize=0&locale=en_US&unit=m&from=38.8941,-77.07556&to=38.84458,-77.07823
```

But I want to find the route that passes via specified location,How to achieve this?

Comment: This is not (yet) an OL 3 question. You have to overcome some basic steps first. For example, how do you get your route from MapQuest? Which format is the response?

Comment: If you want an example take this - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/.